# Magento 1.9 get all avaialble sizes for a configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am creating a script that will export certain products (configurable) to a CSV file with custom structure. However, I am stuck at the point where I need to write all available sizes for a product as a comma-separated list (fields are enclosed).
My problem is that I cannot get the sizes at all. I followed the instructions on [this page](https://www.atwix.com/magento/configurable-product-attributes/), but I get nothing but errors.

This is how my script starts (some stuff missing)

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); //enabled
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4); //catalog, search
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$prodIds=$products->getAllIds();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
foreach($prodIds as $productId) {
  // more code here
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Could you post the code where you try to get the sizes so that we can help you debug it?

Comment: It is the code that is on the link I posted. The second block in particular...

Comment: As this is Inchoo, I assume code they posted there works fine. Posting your own code would help figure out why this is not working fine for you.